# Android - changing priority of native threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, audio, openal

I was wondering if it is possible to change priority of threads in native code, and if it has any effect in Android. From what I've heard, changing prio has no actual affect in the OS, but is it true?

Basically I need to set my audio player thread (I am using a Android openAL port) to highest priority if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether it helps you now, because its been a year when this question was originally posted.

I encountered the same problem, as you have mentioned here and also found the solution for it.

This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9394426/1626878) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <unistd.h>

int nice(int incr);
```

See [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/nice.html)