# Is there a way to assign high priority to a thread or an application in Android?

Tags: android, streaming, datagram, thread-priority

I wrote an Android app that receives UDP packets (that are being streamed) and plays then right when they are received. The app works fine until I click on another app on the Android cell phone, at that time I can hear clicking noise.

Is there any way to get ride of this?
I thought if I can assign a high priority to the thread responsible to receive and play packets, or if I can assign a high priority to this app may help this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to change the priority of native threads, then this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019137/changing-thread-priority-doesnt-have-an-effect/9394426#9394426) might help you.

Comment: I tried to use: `Thread.currentThread().setPriority(0);` but my app now force closes.

Comment: Bit late now, but most likely an IllegalArgumentException.  Use the constants in the [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority(int)) class, such as `Thread.MIN_PRIORITY` (value _1_), or `Thread.MAX_PRIORITY` (value _10_).

Comment: @cafelatte It says in the docs for MAX_PRIORITY that is corresponds to         Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_DISPLAY but is NOT the same value. Coincidentally, I was testing a VPN application which network throughput was limited by CPU performance. When I used the Thread.MAX_PRIORITY value I managed to get 6mbit/s, whereas with the THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_DISPLAY I was able to maintain a throughput around 25mbit/s. Thus in my specific case, it seems like URGENT_DISPLAY gives better performance.